# What is the data type for length property for Java arrays?

Tags: java, types, limits

I want to find out if length property for Java arrays is an int/long or something else.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It is an int. See the [Java Language Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/arrays.html#10.7), section 10.7.

Comment: I really can't see anything forbidding the use of a long, for instance on a platform where that is more performant. You just can't index it with anything bigger than an int. It's a theoretical discussion at this point though. (Yeah, I saw the example but that's not normative).

Answer (score 6):

In [Java Language spec, Arrays](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/arrays.html) you can see in 10.4:

> Arrays must be indexed by int values;
>   short, byte, or char values may also
>   be used as index values because they
>   are subjected to unary numeric
>   promotion and become int values.
>   An attempt to access an array
>   component with a long index value
>   results in a compile-time error.

I could not find the type of the length attribute, but it is at least an int; and if it's a long then you can not access elements beyond the max integer length.

So I guess it's a (final) int.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/arrays.doc.html#62964), it's an `int`

Answer (score 1):

The data type is **int**, not long. Same as the index.

See http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/arrays.doc.html, 10.4

Answer (score 0):

In JavaCard array indexes are shorts, but JavaCard is odd like that. Everywhere else, int like everyone else says.